# How to neutralize the flavor of vanilla?

Tags: vanilla

Out of curiosity, is there any flavour that neutralizes or balances out with vanilla?

Comment: In what? How would this be used?

Comment: I had candies in mind. I personally don't like a strong vanilla flavor in chocolate based candies and caramels. this could be used if you accidentally put in too much for your own flavor ideas or you used a new brand and didn't check to see it's strength etc.

Comment: Maybe I've not seen the same recipes you have but the chocolate candy recipes I see don't generally call for vanilla at all. Seems like you're trying to solve a hypothetical that can be easily avoided.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be looking for flavor pairings, which is off topic.

Comment: @Catija Maybe take that to meta? While flavor pairing ("what tastes good with X?") is generally off-topic, I believe we've taken a decent number of "how do I cover up this taste?" questions in the past. So I don't think this question is an obvious application of that off-topic policy.

Comment: Not at all "just a flavor pairing" question - there are ingredients that have an inherent but annoying vanilla element (eg some brands of soy yoghurt. Not the vanilla flavoured type, but inherent.), and masking it can be very significant when making savory dishes with these...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it depends on how much is too much vanilla.  If your recipe called for a teaspoon of vanilla and you added a tablespoon, it probably won't be too big a deal.  I often use more vanilla than is called for in recipes.

If you are looking for something to "balance" the flavor a little bit, you could maybe try salt or lemon juice/extract.

If you just prefer that vanilla not be the dominant flavor, there are plenty of things that go nicely with vanilla that would result in a more complex flavor.  Personally, I love combining vanilla with the flavors of fruit or almonds.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I bought some Vanilla Porter beer that was WAY too strong.
I took a couple of tbs of the beer added about 1/3 rd tsp of unsweetened baking chocolate, microwaved it to get it hot so I could mix them, and it did the trick.  It cut the vanila way back and didn't really add much choc flavor at all.